# Modules inside firebase cloud functions with python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a directory structure like this:

```
python-functions/
--src
---- | api/
-------- | __init__.py
-------- | main.py
---- | __init__.py
---- | main.py
```

I'm trying to define all my functions in src/main.py but have the implementations in its corresponding folder

```py
# src/main.py
import src.api.main as api

@https_fn.on_request(timeout_sec=300)
def status(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return api.status(req)
```

```py
# src/api/main.py
def status(req: https_fn.Request):
    return https_fn.Response("Hello", status=200)
```

But when deploying I get this error:

```
# Importing like: import src
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2023 00:09:43] "GET /\_\_/functions.yaml HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error: Failed to parse build specification:

- FirebaseError Expect manifest yaml to specify a version number
```

or this one:

```
# importing like: from .api.main import main
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2023 00:28:19] "GET /__/functions.yaml HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Error: Failed to parse build specification:
- FirebaseError Expect manifest yaml to specify a version number
```

I've tried other ways of importing like but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this by following this comment on a github issue
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/issues/92#issuecomment-1549153623

```py
# Adding this to the top of main.py works as a workaround, but it's not ideal:

import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent.as_posix())

from test import base
```

Comment: Does it work for you after deployment as well? I've tried that and it works in emulator, but in the functions I can see `Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.` what implies file system is being traversed

Comment: Similar solution here: ```sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent))```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Importing with file path using importlib solved my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("firebase_connector", "fn_impl/firebase_connector.py")
firebase_connector_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules["firebase_connector"] = firebase_connector_module
spec.loader.exec_module(firebase_connector_module)
db = firebase_connector_module.db
```