# Firebase Function with Python and more than one file to organize the project

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this function with Python working with Firebase:

- main.py

```
from firebase_admin import initialize_app
from firebase_functions import https_fn
import flask
from flask import jsonify

initialize_app()
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return jsonify({
        'msg': 'Hey Jo!'
    })

@app.get("/hello")
def hello():
    return jsonify({
        'msg': 'Hello flask'
    })

# Expose Flask app as a single Cloud Function:
@https_fn.on_request()
def adama_function(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    with app.request_context(req.environ):
        return app.full_dispatch_request()
```

This was a simple Hello World, but actually I would like to use langchain inside my function.. But I'm having trouble to import other files/classes. For example if I created some file like this:

- testclass.py

```
class Test:
    def test(self) :
        return "Teste"
```

And I would like to import this class in my function, at main.py file:

```
from firebase_admin import initialize_app
from firebase_functions import https_fn
import flask
from flask import jsonify
**from testclass import Test**

initialize_app()
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def root():
    **test = Test()
    msg = test()**
    return jsonify({
        'msg': f'Hey Jo! ${**msg**}'
    })
```

But when I try to deploy functions I got one error:

`firebase deploy --only functions`

`  File "", line 940, in exec_module
File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "..../project/heyjo/main.py", line 5, in 
from testclass import Test
ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'testclass'**

127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2023 08:22:33] "GET /__/functions.yaml HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Error: Failed to parse build specification:

- FirebaseError Expect manifest yaml to specify a version number
  `

I expected to have a Firebase Function that works with multiple files, because I'll neet that to organize the source code of the project.

Comment: Do you have an __init__.py file in the location of the testclass? And I presume these asterisks are not actually in your code?

Answer (score 0):

As the code on the
[Modules inside firebase cloud functions with python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76277551/modules-inside-firebase-cloud-functions-with-python-modulenotfounderror-no-mod)

I could import my packages

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent.as_posix())

from test import base
```